# Can I delete SQL Server 2008 R2 "audittrace" (.trc) files

Tags: sql-server, audit

This is precaution question :)

---

When I was configuring SQL Server 2008 R2 database engine, I checked *"Enable C2 audits"* which I don't really need. From that time it created a lot of files like *audittrace20130918235148.trc*. I disabled C2 auditing in SQL Server Management Studio by unchecking checkbox.

---

**Are those files really from C2 audit? If so, can I safely remove them without worring about data stored in databases?** Again: I do *not* need audit logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are those files really from C2 audit?

The audit file format is **audittraceyyyymmddHHMMSS.trc**

After you disable `C2 audit` using

```
EXEC sp_configure 'c2 audit mode', 0
go
reconfigure with override
```

and you are absolutely sure that you dont need the audit files, you can delete the files.

> If so, can I safely remove them without worring about data stored in databases?

The C2 Audit Mode uses SQL Trace to capture audit events, which are stored in trace files i.e. they are not stored in database, unless you have a job that loads the files into a database.

**Note** : The C2 security standard has been superseded by [Common Criteria Certification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326650%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much Sir, I did as you said and everything seams to be fine!